# problem by <input asp-for='files' /> in Custom tag helper

Tags: asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I created a custom tagHelper.
But I have encountered a problem to develop the code snippet displayed(input asp-for="files" Exactly transmitted to the browser).

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output){
var form = @"<form id='uploadFileForm' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'  >
        <input asp-for='files' />
        <input type = 'button' id ='btnUpload' value =' upload' />
        </form > ";
output.PreContent.AppendHtmlLine(form);}
```

and my model :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a file.")]
[DataType(DataType.Upload)]
public IList<IFormFile> files { get; set; }
```

More explanation : When using

```
<input asp-for='files' />
```

in a view, the following code is finally generated in 
browser:

```
<input type="file" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a file." id="files" multiple="multiple" name="files" />
```

Now, I do not know what to do in tagHelper to generate the same output in the above line by taghelper.
please help me

Comment: More explanation : When using

<input asp-for='files' />
in a view, the following code is finally generated in browser:

<input type="file" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a file." id="files" multiple="multiple" name="files" />
Now, I do not know what to do in tagHelper to generate the same output in the above line by taghelper. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look the docu (change the version if its not the right one): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Gathering from the example there, what you are looking for should look like this
**(untested example)**:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output){

    // Should already be input, but in case you want to change it to something else
    output.TagName = "input";

    // remove the old attribute
    // You probably need to do something different if you want to carry over the attribute
    output.Attributes.RemoveAll("asp-for");      

    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("type", "file");
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-val", "true");
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-val-required", "Please select a file.");
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("id", "files");
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("multiple", "multiple");
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("name", "files");
}
```

---

I am not sure whether you actually can use this for a predefined tag (like input), you might be better of if you create a custom one (something that does not exist already).

As you haven`t posted any example for the Annotation you use, lets say you change it to:

```
<custominput asp-for='files' />
```

then there should be something like this on you TagHelper Class.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("custominput", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
```

---

The example above ignores your model, so I assume that if you want to use it you need to somehow provide it to your TagHelper Class, and change the SetAttribute lines accordingly.

Comment: As you can see in my example
The form information is placed inside a string and is sent to the browser in the same way.
My goal is to ultimately this:
<input asp-for = 'files' />
By razor this:
<input type = "file" data-val = "true" data -val-required = "Please select a file." id = "files" multiple = "multiple" name = "files" />
Converts like when it is directly inside a view

Comment: What do you want to say when you write 'by razor this'? I assumed you want to replace the one with the other, but apparently this is not the case. You should probably update the question with a more detailed explanation about what the output should actually look like.

Comment: Forgive me first for the weakness I have in English.
Yes, you just realized. Let me explain a bit more.
Suppose this code
<input asp-for = 'files' />
  Inserted inside a view. After running and seeing the source code in the browser with this
<input type = "file" date -val = "true" date -val-required = "Please select a file." id = "files" multiple = "multiple" name = "files" />
 You will encounter
But how should this output get to this example? Please try it once in a practical way. Maybe I want to do it